# Random Api name with totalusers getting called in my next.js 13 project

Tags: next.js13, issue-tracking

I have a project in next.js 13 and somehow a GET API is getting called from [This Link](https://backend.fooddy.in/dashboard/totalusers).
Does anyone know about this?

whenever i am refreshing my page this GET api is getting called for no reason.

Also the api Preview shows this..
`message :  "Users count" swiggyUsers :  "53186" zomatoUsers :  "57287"`

and response is
{"message":"Users count","swiggyUsers":"53186","zomatoUsers":"57287"}